# Android Bluetooth Received Serial Data Garbled

Tags: java, android, matlab, bluetooth

I've gone through the following thread for my doubt. But, it's still unclear.

[Why does the serial BT data I received get chopped out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483342/why-does-the-serial-bt-data-i-received-get-chopped-out)

Chris, that's a nice workaround you suggested. In the solutions you've provided, the one with appending '\n' is suitable for me as I'm purely transmitting float values from my PC (MATLAB) - after converting to string - to my Android phone. I'm using the following code to group data by searching for '\n' but still the received data is sometimes garbled up. Please tell me what I've to change.

```
aReader = new InputStreamReader( mmInStream );
mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader( aReader );
aString = mBufferedReader.readLine();
mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothActivity.MESSAGE_READ, aString).sendToTarget();
```

This is what I have in the handler to display the data:

```
String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
        try{
            float readM = Float.parseFloat(readMessage);
            text.append("\n" + readM);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            text.append("\n Number Format Exception!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is wrong with this kind of reception? It will be nice if you could answer a bit quickly as this is the concluding part of my project and the deadline is nearing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I myself solved this. I changed my delimiter from '\n' to 'N' (since no characters are part of my data which are float values) and I've achieved satisfactory transmission rate with more than 99% data integrity (out of 2000 samples that I sent at a rate of 600 samples per second from MATLAB, only 10 got garbled) at the receiver (my App). But, thanks for the idea @Chris Stratton!