# Serial BT data from Arduino is chopped up in Android, how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

The exact problem I am having is the same as in this thread:

[Why does the serial BT data I received get chopped out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483342/why-does-the-serial-bt-data-i-received-get-chopped-out)

So I know I need to make delimiters and parse, which I what I need, but sadly the answer to that thread wasn't specific enough.

I need to send analog data (from 0-1023) in the Arduino over to the Android device, so I added a "n" as a delimiter to the end of each string before sending over as such:

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

    int bluetoothTx = 2;
    int bluetoothRx = 3;
    boolean toggle = true;

    SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

    void setup()
    {
      //Setup usb serial connection to computer
      Serial.begin(9600);

      //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
      bluetooth.begin(115200);
      bluetooth.print("$$$");
      delay(100);
      bluetooth.println("U,57600,N");
      bluetooth.begin(57600);
    }

    void loop()
    { 
      //Read from serial to bluetooth

    while(1)   //to reduce jitters
      {
        String sensorString =  String(analogRead(A0), DEC);
        sensorString = sensorString + "n";
        bluetooth.println(sensorString);
        delay(100);
      }
    }
```

This is for the Arduino side.

For the Android side, I used the BluetoothChat example, so in the mHandler and in the switch-case of MESSAGE_READ, the codes are as such:

```
    case MESSAGE_READ:
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
        String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

        mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
```

Where mConversationArrayAdapter is a String ArrayAdapter. May i know how I can modify the code within the MESSAGE_READ case so as to solve this problem?

Comment: First, your choice of "n" sounds like you may have misunderstood the traditional ASCII newline character - an escaped "\n", code 10 decimal or 0xa in hex.  Using a printable letter "n" may still work in your case though, as it appears the rest of your string would be numeric - though if you go through anything which is `line buffered` an "n" won't have the "send this now and don't wait for more" effect that an "\n" would.

Comment: Next, you aren't showing us enough of your code - where is your loop which accumulates input buffer reads until you have enough to parse, and preserves anything remaining in a buffer after an "n" to use as part of the next message?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very sure on what you're asking for, I'm still very new to java. Currently, the arduino sends any number from 0-1023 with a "n" behind it, so I was hoping that on the Android side I can take the numbers with the n, remove the n from the string and then display on the arrayadapter. Would using "\n" be easier?

Comment: Yes, you more or less can do that, though using "\n" would get you more cooperation from anything in between that happened to be looking at the data instead of treating it as arbitrary.  The major logical gap you have right now is the unfounded assumption that a read buffer will contain an entire message.  That's not necessarily the case - you can have the tail end of one message and the beginning of another. You might even get only a single character.  All these cases have to be handled, otherwise you risk dropping messages. Those who skip this create unreliable code - it works *sometimes*

Comment: I see, so you are saying for example if I send for eg 400n, 500n, 600n from the arduino, android could receive it as 40, 0n5, 00, n ... and so on? If so, then what should I do about it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Either stick the buffers back together and manage the leftovers, use a line read method that reads through a newline and so gives you nicely aligned buffers, or read only one character at a time and collect in your own buffer until you see a newline.  Also, add some logging to your program so you can see what is happening (though don't fall into the trap of assuming that it will always behave as it does today - you have a serial stream going through a packetized radio, so can get interesting variation in arrival times, differing behavior depending on RF noise, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the information! Could you provide a coding example of how I can do that, it would help a lot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send a string of ascii characters formed by each nibble of 0-1023 code (2 bytes), and append it by newline character (i.e. /n). As an example if hex code to send is 0x03FF (i.e. 1023 decimal), then string to send will be  0x30,0x33,0x46,0x46,0x0A.